# Python Regex: password must contain at least one uppercase letter and number

Tags: python, regex, flask

I am doing form validation for a password using Python and Flask. The password needs to contain at least *one uppercase letter* and at least *one number*.

My current failed attempt...

```
re.compile(r'^[A-Z\d]$')
```

Comment: `'\d.*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*\d'`

Comment: @PierreLafortune Would you mind explaining your regex? It works I think...

Comment: @PierreLafortune Actually, it doesn't work.

Comment: It works. I just tested on 20 different strings.

Comment: @ea87, looks right to me. How does it fail?

Comment: @PierreLafortune It work on rubular, but fails in my code. Let me check my code and get back to you all. Also, you should answer this using the "Answer Your Question" button so I can give you the answer for the question.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Got it to work. My logic was off. Thanks a ton, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: The most important requirement you can impose on passwords is a minimum length.

Comment: IMO: I would just do two separate checks - one regex for "does this contain a letter" and another regex for "does this contain a number".  Might make more sense in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use the pattern `'\d.*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*\d'` to search for entries that have at least one capital letter and one number. Logically speaking there are only two ways that a capital letter and a number can appear in a string. Either the letter comes first and the number after or the number first and the letter after.

The pipe | indicates 'OR', so we will look at each side separately. `\d.*[A-Z]` matches a number that is followed by a capital letter, `[A-Z].*\d` matches any capital letter that is followed by a number.

```
words = ['Password1', 'password2', 'passwordthree', 'P4', 'mypassworD1!!!', '898*(*^$^@%&#abcdef']
for x in words:
    print re.search('\d.*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*\d', x)
#<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000088146B0>
#None
#None
#<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000088146B0>
#<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000088146B0>
#None
```

Comment: What if there were more than two conditions? For example, the password must contain at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter, one digit, and one of the following special characters: `!@_$%'. That gives rise to 24 possible orderings. While your approach works for two conditions, it is hardly the best approach to deal with the problem in general.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z]).*\d
```

See [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gF8kU7/1)

The lookahead at `^` start checks if an `[A-Z]` is ahead. If so matches a digit.

Answer (score 3):

To match with string that contains at least one digit character, use:

```
.*[0-9].*
```

The similar regex applies to check for upper/lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions don't have an AND operator, so it's pretty hard to write a regex that matches valid passwords, when validity is defined by something AND something else AND something else.

But, regular expressions do have an OR operator, so just apply DeMorgan's theorem, and write a regex that matches invalid passwords:

anything with no numbers OR anything with no uppercase

So:

```
^([^0-9]*|[^A-Z]*)$
```

If anything matches that, then it's an invalid password.

Comment: the asterisk will match 0 or more character...hence remove it..also this can be done like [^0-9A-Z]

Comment: @repzero, no that's incorrect.   My regex matches "1" and "A".  yours does not

Comment: Note that it's for *matching* a string, not *searching* in a string, if that makes a difference to whatever you were thinking

Comment: Still have to argue, but I put in the anchors to make it clear that you're supposed to match the whole string

Comment: The RE is correct. Maybe you should emphasize this RE is to **match invalid** passwords - you were unfairly dv because that was not clear, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*$
```

Comment: With a lot of answers posted you can't afford yourself "I think". Either it works or not. If not.. don't post because the answer should substantially add something so we can learn from it. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

Using two, non-greedy lookahead assertions:

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])
```

The above asserts that the current input position (the start of string), consists of 0 or more non-capital letters followed by a capital letter and it also consists of 0 or more non digits followed by a digit.

```python
import re

tests = [
    'x1bcAd',
    'xAbcd1d',
    'abcde',
    '1234',
    'AAAA'
]

for test in tests:
    m = re.match(r'^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])', test)
    print(test, 'Passed' if m else 'Failed')
```

Prints:

```
x1bcAd Passed
xAbcd1d Passed
abcde Failed
1234 Failed
AAAA Failed
```